# How do I select a direct child of "this element" in JSoup

Tags: jsoup

If I have an element that looks like this:

```
<foo>
    <bar> bar text 1 </bar>
    <baz>
        <bar> bar text 2 </bar>
    </baz>
</foo>
```

And I already have the `<foo>` element selected, and I want to select the `<bar>` element that is a direct child of `<foo>` but not the one that is a child of `<baz>`, how do I specify that?

```
Element foo = <that thing above>
foo.select("bar").text();
```

yields `"bar text 1 bar text 2"`

what I want is something like

```
foo.select("this > bar").text();
```

The question is: **how do I specify *"this element"* in the selector?**

Note that the desired `bar` might not be first -- I need a solution that would also work for:

```
<foo>
    <baz>
        <bar> bar text 2 </bar>
    </baz>
    <bar> bar text 1 </bar>
</foo>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `:root` structural pseudo-element to specify "this element".  From the [`Element.select` Javadoc](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select%28java.lang.String%29), we see `select` uses "this element as the starting context" and can match "this element, or any of its children"; that is, `:root` refers to the this element, not the actual document root.  The following code demonstrates by placing the second example in some outer tags:

```
//nest your second sample in some fake outer html body
Element html = (Element)Parser.parseFragment("<html><body><foo>\n" +
                "    <baz>\n" +
                "        <bar> bar text 2 </bar>\n" +
                "    </baz>\n" +
                "    <bar> bar text 1 </bar>\n" +
                "</foo></body></html>", null, "http://example.com").get(0);
Element foo = html.select("foo").first();

System.out.println(foo.select(":root > bar"));
```

This code prints

```
<bar>
  bar text 1 
</bar>
```

correctly skipping the nested `bar` element.

According to the [Jsoup changelog](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/CHANGES), structural pseudo-element support was added in 1.7.2.

Comment: that looks like it should work based on the documentation, but for some reason I am getting `SelectorParseException: Could not parse query ':root > bar': unexpected token at ':root > bar'` when I try it :-/

Answer (score 4):

I believe you want:

```
foo.select("> bar").text();
```

see jsoup [Selectors](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) page, `Combinators` section:

> ```
> E > F     an F direct child of E
> ```